# Implementing OpenID-selector + dotnetopenauth

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, openid, openid-selector

I'm in need of a How To as I really can't figure out how to make this work with the New project MVC 2 template.

What should my database look like and how is the original login method replaced with this?

Thanks M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you seen the OpenID project template on the VS Gallery?  That includes the db schema and sample code.

Comment: Here's the link: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/81153747-70d7-477b-b85a-0374e7edabef